# ERROR: No matching distribution found for faster-than-requests

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the package `faster-than-requests` on Windows with the comamnd `pip install faster-than-requests` but am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement faster-than-requests (from versions: c66bdc9, d4d03a6, eb38cdb, 49d49f0, 272d664, 21.3.1, 21.3.2, 21.3.3, 57rc7862, 3572925)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for faster-than-requests
```

(The full error message is here: https://pastebin.com/NcdDYXwQ)

The package installs fine with the same command on Ubuntu 20.10.

I've read the issue opened here: https://github.com/juancarlospaco/faster-than-requests/issues/134 but it seems like the package author doesn't know of a good fix for it, hence why I am asking here.

Comment: Based on the error, this package requires Python >=3.6. Is it possible you have different versions of Python on Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: @sagar1025 Thanks for your comment. They do have different versions (I have 3.9.6 on Windows and 3.8 on Ubuntu). However they are both >= 3.6 - would that still cause issues?

Comment: Just went through the Github issue. It is definitely a `pypi` issue. Couple of things you can try:
`pip install faster-than-requests==21.03.03` 
This is command mentioned in the official `pypi` website
https://pypi.org/project/faster-than-requests/21.03.03/#history
If this doesn't work, try to install a previous version
`pip install faster-than-requests==21.03.02`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried those suggestions but am still receiving the error. I think I will just do the development on ubuntu then, seems to be some sort of windows/pypi problem